# reduce without lambda

Tags: python, reduce

I succeeded in writing some code which returns true if all items in a list are prime numbers.
I think this is a good candidate for `reduce` - up to now I have only used `reduce` in conjunction with `lambda` - is it possible to avoid `lambda` and use a direct function?

```
def is_prime(list):
    np = "Prime"
    for n in list:
        if n < 2:
            np = "NonPrime"
            print np
            # return np
        else:
            for i in range(3, n):   #int(math.sqrt(n))
                if n % i == 0:
                    np ="NonPrime"
                    print np
    return np
```

Comment: Yes. Anywhere you can use a `lambda` you can use a normal function defined with `def`. The converse is not true.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to refactor this code into checking if a number is prime and then using that to test if a list of numbers are `all()` prime. `all()` would be better than `reduce()` because it will short circuit.

Note: you shouldn't use `list` as a variable or argument as it hides the python builtin type.

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(3, n):   #int(math.sqrt(n))
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def all_primes(iterable):
    return all(is_prime(n) for n in iterable)

>>> all_primes([2,3,5,7])
True
>>> all_primes([2,3,5,8])
False
```

If you really wanted to implement this as `reduce()` then, you are effectively reducing a list of booleans to a single boolean using `and`, there is an operator for `and` defined in the `operator` module, `operator.and_`:

```
from functools import reduce   # Py3
import operator as op

def all_primes(iterable):
    return reduce(op.and_, (is_prime(n) for n in iterable))
```

Comment: @joe don't edit my answer, update your question for clarification. I reviewed your edits, you seem to be misunderstanding how `reduce()` works `reduce(func, [a, b, c])` is equivalent to `func(func(a, b), c)` so `func()` has to return a valid arg to `func()`, but your example is `func(int, int) -> str` which can't work in a `reduce()`